# remove some code from the url pagination

Tags: coldfusion

i have the following code, but i am very loose in the regular expression, i am using coldfusion

and i want to remove the code which is inbetween before every next page call

```
http://beta.mysite.com/?jobpage=2page=2#brands
```

what i am trying is if `jobpage` exists, it should remove the `jobpage=2` from the URL, `{2}` is dynamic as it can be one or `2` or `3` and so on.

I tried with `listfirst` and `listlast` or `gettoken` but no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you

```
<Cfset myurl = "http://beta.mysite.com/?jobpage=2page=2##brands" />
<cfoutput>#myurl#</cfoutput><br><Br>
<cfset myurl = ReReplaceNoCase(myurl,"(jobpage=[0-9]+[\&]?)","","ALL") />
<cfoutput>#myurl#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: haha - just gave the same answer - will delete mine as yours was first